# Running a "rundll32.exe" process at Win7 Logon, Lock, & Switch User screens?

Tags: windows-7, scheduled-tasks, group-policy, startupscript, rundll32

Before I start, another post for something similar to this request for help is located at [Running a process at the Windows 7 Welcome Screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3070152/running-a-process-at-the-windows-7-welcome-screen), but the responses were not quite what I believe I am looking for, and the post is over a year old so I thought it best to start a new thread for my needs.

In Windows 7 Ultimate, I am trying to create a script or task scheduler event that will run a Windows "rundll32.exe" process with arguments at the logon, lock, and switch user screens (basically any screen that is waiting for user to log into the machine).

I have tried using the startup script controls in group policy editor as well as creating a task scheduler event, but so far I am unable to get the process to display on the logon screens.

The command line I am using does work while logged into any account at any user level via the "Run.." dialog as well as via CMD prompt, and is only creating a popup that already exists in the Windows OEM Environment.

The hardest part is this: My friend just bought a new laptop. The new laptop came with this specific feature already enabled, but I have no idea what is making it happen and do not have access to the computer to check out gpedit.msc and task scheduler for possible solutions.

There are two reasons why I need this info: 1) I want the feature to work on my own laptop, and 2) my friend would like help disabling it on his as he doesn't like it.

I have been all over Google, posted at Microsoft Answers, and also posted on the laptop manufacturer's user forums. I have found very few pages that refer to the same question as I have, but none have answers that work, and since I have seen and know that this is possible, I am compelled to continue looking.

The laptop that this is currently working on was purchased with a fresh install of Win 7 Ultimate and no manufacturer bloatware/additional software added, so we know that the feature was made to happen by whomever it was that installed the OS and configured it for sale. Therefore I am certain it is just a matter of the right task or script in Windows itself before I see the results I need and then know how to direct my friend to disable his via phone.

The specific call is "rundll32.exe van.dll,RunVAN". In task scheduler I have set this to run as "SYSTEM" and set the triggers for startup, workstation lock, and local disconnect. I have tried using full path to rundll32.exe as well as the bare command. In gpedit startup scripts I have tried full path and bare command. Neither of which for either case is making this popup show on the logon screens.

Any and all help and/or advice on this would be greatly appreciated by both myself and my friend.

Answer (score 0):

[dynamic display of images for the credential provider](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowssecurity/thread/e33ac865-10fa-4050-b291-26a1d47eb3fc)