# Running process before windows logon screen

Tags: c#, windows, windows-services, pinvoke

I tried to run `clac.exe` process before(or exactly when) windows(7 and xp) logon screen is shown.

I tried the `gpedit.msc` method(add calc.exe to `Startup`), `onLogin/onLogout` works only.

Then I created a new windows service,

code (most of my code from: [Running a Form in Windows Logon Screen C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9481621/running-a-form-in-windows-logon-screen-c-sharp)):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace WindowsService2
{
    public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
    {
        public Service1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        [DllImport("Kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
        public static extern int WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId();

        [DllImport("wtsapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern bool WTSQueryUserToken(UInt32 sessionId, out IntPtr Token);

        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        private extern static bool DuplicateTokenEx(
            IntPtr hExistingToken,
            uint dwDesiredAccess,
            ref SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpTokenAttributes,
            SECURITY_IMPERSONATION_LEVEL ImpersonationLevel,
            TOKEN_TYPE TokenType,
            out IntPtr phNewToken);

        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        static extern bool CreateProcessAsUser(
            IntPtr hToken,
            string lpApplicationName,
            string lpCommandLine,
            ref SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpProcessAttributes,
            ref SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpThreadAttributes,
            bool bInheritHandles,
            uint dwCreationFlags,
            IntPtr lpEnvironment,
            string lpCurrentDirectory,
            ref STARTUPINFO lpStartupInfo,
            out PROCESS_INFORMATION lpProcessInformation);     
        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        internal static extern bool AdjustTokenPrivileges(IntPtr tokenhandle,
                                 [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)] bool disableAllPrivileges,
                                 [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct)]ref TOKEN_PRIVILEGES newstate,
                                 uint bufferlength, IntPtr previousState, IntPtr returnlength);
        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        static extern bool OpenProcessToken(IntPtr ProcessHandle,
            UInt32 DesiredAccess, out IntPtr TokenHandle);
        public const UInt32 STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED = 0x000F0000;
        public const UInt32 STANDARD_RIGHTS_READ = 0x00020000;
        public const UInt32 TOKEN_ASSIGN_PRIMARY = 0x0001;
        public const UInt32 TOKEN_DUPLICATE = 0x0002;
        public const UInt32 TOKEN_IMPERSONATE = 0x0004;
        public const UInt32 TOKEN_QUERY = 0x0008;
        public const UInt32 TOKEN_QUERY_SOURCE = 0x0010;
        public const UInt32 TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES = 0x0020;
        public const UInt32 TOKEN_ADJUST_GROUPS = 0x0040;
        public const UInt32 TOKEN_ADJUST_DEFAULT = 0x0080;
        public const UInt32 TOKEN_ADJUST_SESSIONID = 0x0100;
        public const UInt32 TOKEN_READ = (STANDARD_RIGHTS_READ | TOKEN_QUERY);
        public const UInt32 TOKEN_ALL_ACCESS = (STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED | TOKEN_ASSIGN_PRIMARY |
            TOKEN_DUPLICATE | TOKEN_IMPERSONATE | TOKEN_QUERY | TOKEN_QUERY_SOURCE |
            TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES | TOKEN_ADJUST_GROUPS | TOKEN_ADJUST_DEFAULT |
            TOKEN_ADJUST_SESSIONID);
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
        {
            public int nLength;
            public IntPtr lpSecurityDescriptor;
            public int bInheritHandle;
        }
        enum SECURITY_IMPERSONATION_LEVEL
        {
            SecurityAnonymous,
            SecurityIdentification,
            SecurityImpersonation,
            SecurityDelegation
        }

        public enum TOKEN_TYPE
        {
            TokenPrimary = 1,
            TokenImpersonation
        }
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct TOKEN_PRIVILEGES
        {
            public UInt32 PrivilegeCount;
            public LUID Luid;
            public UInt32 Attributes;
            public LUID_AND_ATTRIBUTES[] Privileges;
        }
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct LUID
        {
            public uint LowPart;
            public int HighPart;
        }
        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        static extern bool LookupPrivilegeValue(string lpSystemName, string lpName,
            out LUID lpLuid);
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        struct STARTUPINFO
        {
            public Int32 cb;
            public string lpReserved;
            public string lpDesktop;
            public string lpTitle;
            public Int32 dwX;
            public Int32 dwY;
            public Int32 dwXSize;
            public Int32 dwYSize;
            public Int32 dwXCountChars;
            public Int32 dwYCountChars;
            public Int32 dwFillAttribute;
            public Int32 dwFlags;
            public Int16 wShowWindow;
            public Int16 cbReserved2;
            public IntPtr lpReserved2;
            public IntPtr hStdInput;
            public IntPtr hStdOutput;
            public IntPtr hStdError;
        }
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        internal struct PROCESS_INFORMATION
        {
            public IntPtr hProcess;
            public IntPtr hThread;
            public int dwProcessId;
            public int dwThreadId;
        }
[Flags]
    enum CreateProcessFlags : uint
    {
        DEBUG_PROCESS = 0x00000001,
        DEBUG_ONLY_THIS_PROCESS = 0x00000002,
        CREATE_SUSPENDED = 0x00000004,
        DETACHED_PROCESS = 0x00000008,
        CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE = 0x00000010,
        NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS = 0x00000020,
        IDLE_PRIORITY_CLASS = 0x00000040,
        HIGH_PRIORITY_CLASS = 0x00000080,
        REALTIME_PRIORITY_CLASS = 0x00000100,
        CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP = 0x00000200,
        CREATE_UNICODE_ENVIRONMENT = 0x00000400,
        CREATE_SEPARATE_WOW_VDM = 0x00000800,
        CREATE_SHARED_WOW_VDM = 0x00001000,
        CREATE_FORCEDOS = 0x00002000,
        BELOW_NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS = 0x00004000,
        ABOVE_NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS = 0x00008000,
        INHERIT_PARENT_AFFINITY = 0x00010000,
        INHERIT_CALLER_PRIORITY = 0x00020000,
        CREATE_PROTECTED_PROCESS = 0x00040000,
        EXTENDED_STARTUPINFO_PRESENT = 0x00080000,
        PROCESS_MODE_BACKGROUND_BEGIN = 0x00100000,
        PROCESS_MODE_BACKGROUND_END = 0x00200000,
        CREATE_BREAKAWAY_FROM_JOB = 0x01000000,
        CREATE_PRESERVE_CODE_AUTHZ_LEVEL = 0x02000000,
        CREATE_DEFAULT_ERROR_MODE = 0x04000000,
        CREATE_NO_WINDOW = 0x08000000,
        PROFILE_USER = 0x10000000,
        PROFILE_KERNEL = 0x20000000,
        PROFILE_SERVER = 0x40000000,
        CREATE_IGNORE_SYSTEM_DEFAULT = 0x80000000,
    }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct LUID_AND_ATTRIBUTES
        {
            public LUID Luid;
            public UInt32 Attributes;
        }

        public class RunProcess
        {
            public void log(string error)
            {
                throw new Exception(error);
            }
            public void StartProcess(string pathOrName)
            {
                Process winLogon = null;
                foreach (Process p in Process.GetProcesses())
                {
                    if (p.ProcessName.Contains("winlogon"))
                    {
                        winLogon = p;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                // grab the winlogon's token
                IntPtr userToken = IntPtr.Zero;
                if (!OpenProcessToken(winLogon.Handle, TOKEN_QUERY | TOKEN_IMPERSONATE | TOKEN_DUPLICATE, out userToken))
                {
                    log("ERROR: OpenProcessToken returned false - " + Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
                }
                WTSQueryUserToken((uint)WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId(), out userToken);
                // create a new token
                IntPtr newToken = IntPtr.Zero;
                SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES tokenAttributes = new SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES();
                tokenAttributes.nLength = Marshal.SizeOf(tokenAttributes);
                SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES threadAttributes = new SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES();
                threadAttributes.nLength = Marshal.SizeOf(threadAttributes);
                // duplicate the winlogon token to the new token
                if (!DuplicateTokenEx(userToken, 0x10000000, ref tokenAttributes, SECURITY_IMPERSONATION_LEVEL.SecurityImpersonation,
                    TOKEN_TYPE.TokenImpersonation, out newToken))
                {
                    log("ERROR: DuplicateTokenEx returned false - " + Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
                }

                TOKEN_PRIVILEGES tokPrivs = new TOKEN_PRIVILEGES();
                tokPrivs.PrivilegeCount = 1;
                LUID seDebugNameValue = new LUID();
                if (!LookupPrivilegeValue(null, "SeDebugPrivilege", out seDebugNameValue))
                {
                    log("ERROR: LookupPrivilegeValue returned false - " + Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
                }

                tokPrivs.Privileges = new LUID_AND_ATTRIBUTES[1];
                tokPrivs.Privileges[0].Luid = seDebugNameValue;
                tokPrivs.Privileges[0].Attributes = 0x00000002;
                if (!AdjustTokenPrivileges(newToken, false, ref tokPrivs, 0, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero))
                {
                    log("ERROR: AdjustTokenPrivileges returned false - " + Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
                }
                PROCESS_INFORMATION pi = new PROCESS_INFORMATION();
                STARTUPINFO si = new STARTUPINFO();
                si.cb = Marshal.SizeOf(si);
                si.lpDesktop = "Winsta0\\Winlogon";

                // start the process using the new token
                 if (!CreateProcessAsUser(newToken, "calc.exe", null, ref tokenAttributes, ref threadAttributes,true, (uint)CreateProcessFlags.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE | (uint)CreateProcessFlags.INHERIT_CALLER_PRIORITY, IntPtr.Zero,"C:\\Windows\\System32", ref si, out pi))
                {
                    log("ERROR: CreateProcessAsUser returned false - " + Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
                }

                Process _p = Process.GetProcessById(pi.dwProcessId);
                if (_p != null)
                {
                    log("Process " + _p.Id + " Name " + _p.ProcessName);
                }
                else
                {
                    log("Not Found");
                }
            }
      }           
        RunProcess r = new RunProcess();
        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            r.StartProcess("calc.exe");
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            r.log("Stoped");
        }
    }
}
```

I installed the service by this line:

```
"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\installutil.exe" "c:\myservice.exe"
```

and now I did restart.

And then I checked if the process in running when the logon screen is shown and then I found out that there is no calculator window and there is no process named `calc` running.

And then I saw that "`WindowsService2`" is not running (on the `taskmgr`).

So I think that it can be fixed (I will not give up so fast, i have to finish it today), the question is:

Why its not working, what i need to do now to check why its not working?

I prefer:

There is any other way(or ways) to run process before logon screen(XP and Windows 7)?

(good answer is good example plus good explanation) :)

**Edit:**

the solution is in the installtion,
the installation log:

```
Installing assembly 'c:\WindowsService2.exe'.
Affected parameters are:
   logtoconsole = 
   logfile = c:\WindowsService2.InstallLog
   assemblypath = c:\WindowsService2.exe
No public installers with the RunInstallerAttribute.Yes attribute could be found in the c:\WindowsService2.exe assembly.
Committing assembly 'c:\WindowsService2.exe'.
Affected parameters are:
   logtoconsole = 
   logfile = c:\WindowsService2.InstallLog
   assemblypath = c:\WindowsService2.exe
No public installers with the RunInstallerAttribute.Yes attribute could be found in the c:\WindowsService2.exe assembly.
Remove InstallState file because there are no installers.
```

cant install because:

```
No public installers with the RunInstallerAttribute.Yes attribute could be found in the c:\WindowsService2.exe assembly.
```

what should i do now? :S
(i tried `public static readonly RunInstallerAttribute Yes;` and i even tried to run the `cmd.exe` as administrator)

Comment: did you sent startup type to auto for your service?

Comment: do you mean 'ServiceStartMode.Automatic'? yes.

Comment: I mean open control panel -> administrative tools -> services -> find your service and check startup type

Comment: If you could show your process on the login screen, just imagine what cool malware you could install.

Comment: @IlyaBursov i checked it, my service is not there(the installation process is not finished successfully) , read my update ,maybe you know what to do next.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I'm trying to do exactly the opposite, my process purpose is to verify the user.

Comment: read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a(v=vs.110).aspx - this will solve your service problem, but you should take in account that your service can start before winlogon is executed

Comment: @IlyaBursov thank you =), i will check it, another small question:
there is an software named "LockMyPc" : http://fspro.net/lock-pc/ this software is starting before windows logon screen and even if you are in safe mode this software will appears.(how they did it?)

Comment: @user2904123 looks like they'are using windows hooks

Comment: Well, there are officially supported ways to do that.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3070152/running-a-process-at-the-windows-7-welcome-screen/70647248#70647248

Answer (score -1):

to start your application before start up there are three options:

you can add a new registry value by using `mscorlib.dll`(RegistryKey Class) functions and classes:

```
RegistryKey add = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true);
add.SetValue("Your App Name", "\"" + Application.ExecutablePath.ToString() + "\"");
```

other locations:

```
HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce
HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunServices
HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunServicesOnce
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnceEx
```

you can add youre application manually:

```
gpedit.msc->windows settings->script files(startup/shutdown)->startup->add..(choose youre application assembly file)
```

(all gpedit values are saved in the registry, you can also add your application assembly path by using `GPMGMTLib`(to make youre application more convenient))

you can move or copy youre application assembly file to:

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Startup)
```

Comment: They are all post logon

Comment: i already tried all those methods(those methods are working on xp only), thank you about all your investment if you will find any alternative/s let me know about it =).

Comment: It seems to work only with windows xp, i'am join to youre question.