# Running a Process (WITH GUI) on Windows XP Logon Screen (.NET / Pinvoke)

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, service, windows-xp

I need to write a small **service** that runs an application (with gui, e.g. *calc.exe*) on the logon-screen.

I already found this question (and answer):
[Running a process at the Windows 7 Welcome Screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3070152/running-a-process-at-the-windows-7-welcome-screen)

please read the code-comments if you don't understand how this works:

```
        // grab the winlogon process
        Process winLogon = null;
        foreach (Process p in Process.GetProcesses())
        {
            if (p.ProcessName.Contains("winlogon"))
            {
                winLogon = p;
                break;
            }
        }
        // grab the winlogon's token
        IntPtr userToken = IntPtr.Zero;
        if (!OpenProcessToken(winLogon.Handle, TOKEN_QUERY | TOKEN_IMPERSONATE | TOKEN_DUPLICATE, out userToken))
        {
            log("ERROR: OpenProcessToken returned false - " + Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
        }

        // create a new token
        IntPtr newToken = IntPtr.Zero;
        SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES tokenAttributes = new SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES();
        tokenAttributes.nLength = Marshal.SizeOf(tokenAttributes);
        SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES threadAttributes = new SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES();
        threadAttributes.nLength = Marshal.SizeOf(threadAttributes);
        // duplicate the winlogon token to the new token
        if (!DuplicateTokenEx(userToken, 0x10000000, ref tokenAttributes, SECURITY_IMPERSONATION_LEVEL.SecurityImpersonation,
            TOKEN_TYPE.TokenImpersonation, out newToken))
        {
            log("ERROR: DuplicateTokenEx returned false - " + Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
        }
        TOKEN_PRIVILEGES tokPrivs = new TOKEN_PRIVILEGES();
        tokPrivs.PrivilegeCount = 1;
        LUID seDebugNameValue = new LUID();
        if (!LookupPrivilegeValue(null, SE_DEBUG_NAME, out seDebugNameValue))
        {
            log("ERROR: LookupPrivilegeValue returned false - " + Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
        }
        tokPrivs.Privileges = new LUID_AND_ATTRIBUTES[1];
        tokPrivs.Privileges[0].Luid = seDebugNameValue;
        tokPrivs.Privileges[0].Attributes = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;
        // escalate the new token's privileges
        if (!AdjustTokenPrivileges(newToken, false, ref tokPrivs, 0, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero))
        {
            log("ERROR: AdjustTokenPrivileges returned false - " + Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
        }
        PROCESS_INFORMATION pi = new PROCESS_INFORMATION();
        STARTUPINFO si = new STARTUPINFO();
        si.cb = Marshal.SizeOf(si);
        si.lpDesktop = "Winsta0\\Winlogon";
        // start the process using the new token
        if (!CreateProcessAsUser(newToken, "calc.exe", null, ref tokenAttributes, ref threadAttributes,
            true, (uint)CreateProcessFlags.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE | (uint)CreateProcessFlags.INHERIT_CALLER_PRIORITY, IntPtr.Zero,
            "C:\\Windows\\System32", ref si, out pi))
        {
            log("ERROR: CreateProcessAsUser returned false - " + Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
        }

        Process _p = Process.GetProcessById(pi.dwProcessId);
        if (_p != null)
        {
            log("Process " + _p.Id + " Name " + _p.ProcessName);
        }
        else
        {
            log("Process not found");
        }
```

It works with Windows 7. With XP I get error 1349 `ERROR_BAD_TOKEN_TYPE` while calling `CreateProcessAsUser` (MSDN: *The type of the token is inappropriate for its attempted use.*).

How to realize this in Windows XP? It does not have to be the code from above but it should work as a service (with system-account?).

Thanks for your support
Fluxer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This definitely has to do with privilege issues (Windows Vista and 7 have notable changes in security). Rather than trying to get token of winlogon.exe and impersonating it, try getting user token via `WTSQueryUserToken` like this:

```
WTSQueryUserToken (WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId(), out userToken);
```

Replace the OpenProcessToken line which is used to get the token with the above statement.

Your new code should be like this:

```
//        if (!OpenProcessToken(winLogon.Handle, TOKEN_QUERY | TOKEN_IMPERSONATE | //TOKEN_DUPLICATE, out userToken))
//        {
//            log("ERROR: OpenProcessToken returned false - " + //Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
//        }

WTSQueryUserToken (WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId(), out userToken);
```

Do your dll import like this:

```
[DllImport("Kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
[return:MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
public static extern int WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId ( );
```

You need only replace the part I commented out with this code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! what should I do with token `&newToken`? just using it for `CreateNewProcessAsUser`?

Comment: thanks for your editing. I replaced the code but still getting Error code 1349 on calling `CreateProcessAsUser`..

Comment: if I do not duplicate token and call `CreateProcessAsUser` with `userToken` instead of `newToken`, the process starts but is not visible. neither in locked nor in unlocked mode of win xp.

Comment: Sorry, had problems getting across because of internet connectivity issues. Can you update the question with your modified code? If this doesn't work, then I guess you should try the scheduling option instead.

Comment: Hello, I tried it with `CreateProcess` and the same startupinfos as above and it works! thank you.