# A program that runs before the computer boots

Tags: passwords, boot, bios

I wanted to create a program that runs before the computer boots the operational sistem.
Something like a program that runs every time you turn you Pc on.
To be more specific I wanted to create a program that requires a password in order to add an extra layer of protection before the computer even boots the operation system

Comment: *"requires a password in order to add an extra layer of protection"* - If that's the end goal then writing your own sounds like overkill.  Take a look at "whole disk encryption".

Answer (score 0):

**BIOS Password:** Usually the BIOS has mechanisms to protect unwanted booting devices: using this feature you can even prevent the machine from booting from a flash drive, for example. With an BIOS password no device boots, neither hard disk nor flash drives. Nothing.

**Data/Disk Encryption:** Another alternative would be to encrypt your hard drive, this is common in Linux OS: even with a bootable flash drive it would not be possible to read the files stored on the OS.

**Program Before OS:** As for running a program before booting in your OS, we must assume that first the computer needs to boot the BIOS, then it would boot that program of yours and only after that, it would start the OS. The problem: programs that are developed in programming languages ​​like C/C++, Python, and Java often go through several layers of 'transformation' until they arrive at instructions level that actually make sense to the hardware. Thus, removing the role of the OS, you would have to work even in these intermediate layers (interfaces), identifying the aspects of specific hardware manufacturing: type of architecture, internal functioning, etc. and programming/structuring the communication with these devices.

Comment: In fact, I've found a question from long time ago that mention that subject: [How to run Application.exe before windows startup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12491364/how-to-run-application-exe-before-windows-startup/12491478). obviously it's still not what you need, but I believe it can help.