# pywin32 TOKEN_PRIVILEGES

Tags: python, service, pywin32, winlogon

So here's the problem : 
I'm trying to make a service that starts another exe to show GUI on the login screen of windows. And the cherry on the top : I wish to implement it in python. After some googling, I found this : [Running a process at the Windows 7 Welcome Screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3070152/running-a-process-at-the-windows-7-welcome-screen) . So I went ahead and converted it almost entirely using pywin32, but there's a problem : I cannot make a PyTOKEN_PRIVILEGES object. Unlike other objects, there was a function to instantiate it, but this one doesn't seem to have any ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

win32security.AdjustTokenPrivileges will accept a sequence of 2-tuples for the TOKEN_PRIVILEGES arg.  See win32\Demos\security\set_file_audit.py for an example.  This is also documented in the help file that comes with Pywin32.

Comment: Thanks. So all that was needed was [(LUID,win32security.SE_whatever)]. Thanks a lot for the clear answer ^^.