# how to send inputs to winlogon in c#

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, desktop, winlogon

How can I change desktops? I am interested in sending mouse events to winlogon desktop(I will run the application on system account). The thing is that nothing happens when I call mouse_event(or any other function(keybd_event,sendinput,sendkeys etc.)
Nothing happens even if I am still on the default desktop.
setthreaddesktop returns true, so that means the change succeded.
I even tried to put a messagebox with the same result.

I created a new thread because otherwise the setthreaddesktop return 170 error code(resource in use).

```
      bool dd = false;
      StringBuilder name = new StringBuilder(200, 200);

       uint sss = 0;
      IntPtr hDesktop = OpenInputDesktop(1, true, desktop_ReadObjects | desktop_WriteObjects);

      System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {   dd = SetThreadDesktop(hDesktop);
            CloseDesktop(hDesktop);
            bool get = GetUserObjectInformation(hDesktop, 2, name, 100, ref sss);
                SendKeys.Send("X");
            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 400, 400, 0, 0);
            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 400, 400, 0, 0);
            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN, 400, 400, 0, 0);
            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP, 400, 400, 0, 0);
}).Wait();
```

Edit: If I don't use SetThreadDesktop mouse_event is working

Thanks,

Comment: I got two thoughts about that:
1) the System-Account is probably non-interactive (it has no mouse)
2) Winlogon is probably security critical, so you should not be able to mess with it.

What do you even want to archive?

Comment: The same thing happens when I am on Default Desktop. I would understand if that was the case only on the Winlogon desktop, but it's not.

Comment: Why do you want to switch users? If you need to run a process as another user, you can use the "runas" command.

Comment: I want to make a remote desktop application. I need to handle the UAC prompt. That's the main issue.

Comment: The UAC-Prompt runs in an "protected desktop" - you probably will not be allowed to send inputs there.

Comment: that's not true. if the application is running on system account you can send inputs. Again, the same thing happens when I am still on Default Desktop.

Answer (score 1):

The Windows logon desktop is protected and requires special permissions to run processes and message loops.

If you're running under SYSTEM, you can duplicate your own security token and change the SessionId with SetTokenInformation to create a new process (using CreateProcessAsUser) on the WinSta0\Winlogon desktop of the target user session.

Alternatively, you can duplicate the security token of another process running as SYSTEM in the target user session, such as winlogon.exe and lsass.exe. See:  [Running a process at the Windows 7 Welcome Screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3070152/running-a-process-at-the-windows-7-welcome-screen)

Either way, you're going to be making a lot of Win32 calls to accomplish this task.