# Prevent users to logon / sessions from service process

Tags: windows, winapi

I have a service that make some hardware/drivers preparations in the Windows. During this process I don't want user to logon, reboot or do whatever can broke the driver installation process.

I want to make it transparent for user, like Windows Update process shows progress before user can log on. The start level of the service is 2.
Is there any way to acquire it via winapi?

As a workaround I can use something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3070152/running-a-process-at-the-windows-7-welcome-screen) and disable users, but it looks weird.

Comment: What's wrong with run on windows startup? Does the process require much time?

Comment: Pretty much. Up to 10-15mins. I want to make some kind of information for user like "please stand by while...". I thought about switching sessions to new virtual desktop etc... but it looks too complicated solution for so easy task