# SetWindowsHookEx callback function does not work on SYSTEM authority

Tags: c++, winapi, keyboard, keyboard-hook, authority

**Environment :**
I am using VS2010 on Win10 x64 [16299.431].
I want to log some keys on my PC using `SetWindowsHookEx` function.

**Ultimate goal :**
If someone type correct password in order, my PC will unlock automatically.

**Problem :**
It doesn't work on `SYSTEM` authority.

**Implementation:**

```
#define LOCK_ENABLE 0
#define LOCK_DISABLE 1

DWORD g_locker = LOCK_DISABLE;
DWORD g_selwrd = -2;
CHAR* g_szpaswd = "heaven";

LRESULT CALLBACK LowLevelKeyboardProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
HOOKPROC LockerPraq();

LRESULT CALLBACK LowLevelKeyboardProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    PKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT p = (PKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT) lParam;

    if(HC_ACTION == nCode)
    {
        switch (wParam)
        {
        case WM_KEYDOWN:        case WM_SYSKEYDOWN:
            switch (p->vkCode)          {
            case VK_HOME:
                g_locker = LOCK_ENABLE;
                g_selwrd = -1;
                break;
            case VK_END:
                g_locker = LOCK_DISABLE;
                g_selwrd = 0;
                break;
            }

            if (LOCK_ENABLE == g_locker)
            {
                if (-1 == g_selwrd)
                    g_selwrd = 0;
                else
                {
                    CHAR szKbdstate[MAX_PATH] = {0};
                    WORD theChar = 0x0000;

                    ToAsciiEx(p->vkCode, p->scanCode, (BYTE*)szKbdstate, &theChar, 0, GetKeyboardLayout(0));
                    if (theChar != g_szpaswd[g_selwrd])
                        g_selwrd = 0;
                    else
                    {
                        g_selwrd++;
                        if (g_selwrd >= strlen(g_szpaswd))
                            UnLockPC();
                    }
                }
            }

            break;
        }

    }


    return CallNextHookEx(NULL, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}

HOOKPROC LockerPraq()
{
    HHOOK hook_install = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, LowLevelKeyboardProc, NULL, 0);
    if (NULL == hook_install)
        return(0);

    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    UnhookWindowsHookEx(hook_install);

    return(0);
}
```

Comment: (also please [dont' include taglines and salutations](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). We have upvotes and accepts. )

Answer (score 3):

The reason why you're not seeing any key presses when Windows is locked or logged off (if that is indeed your issue) is because `Winlogon` runs on its own Desktop.

Winlogon is the process that handles the login and lock screens, and it does so  in a secure way.  It is not well documented by Microsoft but there's an article [here](https://brianbondy.com/blog/100/understanding-windows-at-a-deeper-level-sessions-window-stations-and-desktops) that talks about sessions and desktops in general which you might find helpful.

'SetWindowsHookEx' is [documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990(v=vs.85).aspx) as only hooking applications running on the same desktop as the calling application, so that's the likely cause of your problem.

I doubt there's a way round this.  Winlogon runs on its own desktop for a reason and Microsoft don't want you anywhere near it.

**Edit:** Well, OK, maybe you can sneak your own process in there, see: [Running a process at the Windows 7 Welcome Screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3070152/running-a-process-at-the-windows-7-welcome-screen)